# GNU make 3.81 - how to do '--output-sync=target'

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

The latest version of `make` has an option `--output-sync` that can make the **STDOUT** of each target atomic so that statements from multiple targets are not interleaved when using `make --jobs=N`

Unfortunately, I must use `make v 3.81` because that's the one that comes with our SDK.

To determine whether I need `--output-sync`, I added some 'guard statements' around my targets

```
all: $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp))


%.o: %.cpp  
    @echo BEFORE
    @echo MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    qcc.exe $(CC_FLAGS) $@ $< 
    @echo AFTER
```

The output was very interleaved.

```
AFTER
BEFOREAFTER
AFTER
AFTER
```

Is there a way to emulate the `--output-sync` functionality?

I understand that the build speed may be impacted if, for example, there's a way to 'lock the STDOUT mutex' pre-recipe and release it post-recipe.

I'm fine with modifying each of our targets if that's what it takes.

Comment: Don't use the `-j` option?  That will avoid the interleaving, and is trivial to do without modifying the makefile, and is approximately equivalent to anything you're planning to do, only easier.  Is the feature only in GNU Make 4.2?  Does GNU Make 4.2.1 fix the problem you have with 4.2?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have to use `-j` to get parallel builds. I'll update the post regarding the `make` version.

Answer (score 0):

You could log all outputs of a recipe in a temporary file and cat-remove it at the end:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    @d=$$(mktemp) && \
    echo BEFORE >> $$d 2>&1 && \
    echo MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS) >> $$d 2>&1 && \
    qcc.exe $(CC_FLAGS) $@ $< >> $$d 2>&1 && \
    echo AFTER >> $$d 2>&1 && \
    cat $$d && \
    rm $$d
```

This will not completely prevent interleaving because several `cat` commands could be run in parallel if you have several CPUs, but it should significantly reduce the probability. If you really want to completely avoid interleaving, you will have to add a spin-lock around the `cat` commands. Under a GNU/Linux OS you could have a look at `flock`, for instance:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    @d=$$(mktemp) && \
    echo BEFORE >> $$d 2>&1 && \
    echo MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS) >> $$d 2>&1 && \
    qcc.exe $(CC_FLAGS) $@ $< >> $$d 2>&1 && \
    echo AFTER >> $$d 2>&1 && \
    flock /tmp/my-lock-file cat $$d && \
    rm $$d
```

**Explanations:**

- I transformed your recipe in a single shell invocation (each line in a make recipe is executed in a different shell) such that the `d` shell variable is available in all commands in the list.
- The commands are chained using the `&&` operator: if one fails, the whole list fails with the same exit status and make will tell you that.
- Instead of putting all commands on the same line, which gets quickly unreadable, I added `\` before all end of lines but the last. More readable but still interpreted as a single line by make.
- The first command in the list (`mktemp`) atomically creates a unique temporary file. Use any equivalent available in your environment. Note the double `$` in `d=$$(mktemp)`. It is needed to pass the first expansion by make and to become `d=$(mktemp)` when passed to the shell. Same when referring to the shell expansion of shell variable `d`: `$$d` is first expanded by make as `$d` before being passed to the shell.
- The redirections of the outputs of the commands (`>> $d 2>&1` after first expansion by make) redirect the standard outputs to the temporary file in append mode (`>> $d`) and make the standard error descriptor a copy of the standard output descriptor (`2>&1`) with the effect of also appending the standard errors to the same temporary file.

Comment: To avoid obfuscating recipes, I'd create a script that takes care to serialize output, and use the script in a makefile as a [`SHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html). Also in some cases, [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) may be helpful.

Comment: I can't believe this question is so popular since `gnu make 3.81` is really old! Are so many devs still using it?

Comment: @Adrian Yes, it's on the cluster system I'm using and I can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: *Only on IBM LSF system*

```
lsmake -J <numberofparallelrunjobs> -T <other GNU make parameters> > makeoutput.txt &
less makeoutput.txt
```

E.g. `&/^T5:` or `&/^T6:` to follow only output from 5th or 6th task, respectively.

---

In case you use such an old make because you use an IBM LSF cluster system, you can use the GNU make wrapper `lsmake` that has an option `-T` to tag each output line with a unique task id. If you then redirect the output (perhaps first to a file and then) to `less` you can press e.g. `&` (less will write `&/` at the bottom) `^T12:` `return` to follow only the output from task 12.

When finished, you can use  `sort -t: -k1.2,1 -n -s makeoutput.txt` to see all output in order. (Here, `-t` specifies `:` as field separator such that `-k1.2,1` (second character of first field to end of first field) specifies the task IDs as key (e.g. `12` of `T12: someoutput`) the, `-n` sorts numerically (i.e. 1,9,10 not 1,10,9) `-s` makes the sorting stable (not change order of lines with equal rank))